# Multiple Master_Index entries are coming on job queue on full reindexing the Sitecore_Master_Index

Tags: sitecore-client, solr, content-search, indexing

At the time of `sitecore_master_index` rebuild (full reindexing or on update) we can see multiple `sitecore_master_index` entries in the index job queue. Can anyone explain the reason for this?

[image]

url : `websiteurl/sitecore/admin/jobs.aspx`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `syncMaster` strategy for `sitecore_master_index`, every time you save something in `master` database (or Sitecore itself saves a page, like e.g. information about last execution or scheduled job, changing the state of EXM message, any datasource change), a new backed job is created to updated `sitecore_master_index`.

By default Sitecore does not allow to update same index in parallel. It means that when your `sitecore_master_index` is being fully rebuilt, for like 12 minutes - as on your screenshot, all the partial updates of index triggered by updates of single items, they will be queued.

So in summary: every queued job you see there means that there was a save of a Sitecore item in `master` database during the time your `sitecore_master_index` was being rebuilt.

Comment: Thank you so much for detail explanation, appreciate your help.